# Javascript Date.parse not processing toLocaleDateString() output

Tags: javascript, date

I have an issue with regards to convert dates back from locale to ISO. 
I read a date from mySQL (in ISO Format) and convert it to locale (in my case German / DE-de). The result is OK (e.g. 2010-10-15 => 15.10.2015).
The (after possibly editing it) I need to convert it back to ISO before saving to MySQL. But I can not get it converted back. Date.parse() and Date() reject the input as invalid.

`toLocaleDateString ('1968-03-05')` returns `05.03.1968` **OK**

`Date.parse ('05.03.1968')` returns `NaN` **BAD**

`Date ('05.03.1968')` returns `invalid date` **BAD**

Is there any decent solution out there for this issue?

Otherwise I would have to discard the locale alltogether and implement my own list of supported date-formats and my own conversion functions, which I would preferably not do... Unless I really have to.

Comment: *"Unless I really have to."* You really have to, or use a library that's already done the work for you.

Comment: I have had a look at some libraries (datejs and Moment). However the core issue remains. Without a reliable way to detect the clients locale reliably (which does not seem to be possible) and without a function the does the reverse of "toLocaleDateString()" then, yes I guess I have to implement my own list of supported locales and my own conversion functions.
What I still find strange is that Date.parse does not work... I would have suspected that this is something a lot of people need...

Comment: It is indeed something a lot of people need, and it's one of the biggest un-handled issues with JavaScript in the wild in my view. Re locale: It's not a solved problem. :-| But search on SO (or better, with Google and "site:stackoverflow.com") for "detect locale browser" for several options.

Comment: The referenced question is from 2011 and the proposed solution is from 2008. Are there any newer options?

Answer (score -3):

You can use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) , it is very useful library for handling date objects and strings.

You can something like

```
var date = moment('05.03.1968', 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate();
```

You can then convert this date object to any format.

Comment: I had a quick look at Moment before I posted here. Your "solution" requires to know how the date is represented in the locale on the users machine, which I don't know. If have users with many different locales.. And even if I would know, I would have to implement conversaion routines, if I am not mistaken.